# NextJS + Contentful => getEntries request within getInitialProps breaks production build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful, vercel

**Stack**: NextJS, Contentful + Now

**Overview**: Invoked contentful's getEntries() request within getInitialProps async function. In local environment, everything is working perfectly, I receive the posts then successfully pass them as props to the page where I can render them.

**Issue**: When I try to deploy with Now, I am getting this error:

> Error: The resource could not be found.
>       at notFoundError (/zeit/31b54c53/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:7731:19)
>       at /zeit/31b54c53/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:7854:13
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>       at async Function.module.exports.HB77.Post.getInitialProps (/zeit/31b54c53/.next/serverless/pages/p/[id].js:1198:15)
>       at async loadGetInitialProps (/zeit/31b54c53/.next/serverless/pages/p/[id].js:3451:17) {
>     sys: { type: 'Error', id: 'NotFound' },
>     details: {
>       type: 'Entry',
>       id: 'undefined',
>       environment: 'master',
>       space: undefined
>     }
>   }
>   Error occurred prerendering page "/p/[id]" https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/prerender-error: Error: Failed to render serverless page
>       at Object._default [as default] (/zeit/31b54c53/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:12:212)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

**Code**:

```
const Post = props => {
  ...
}

Post.getInitialProps = async function({ query }) {

  const contentfulClient = contentful.createClient({
    accessToken: `${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    space: `${process.env.SPACE}`
  });

  const res = await contentfulClient.getEntry(`${query.id}`);

  return {
    post: res
  };
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like your ENVs could be lacking:

```
details: { type: 'Entry', id: 'undefined', environment: 'master', space: undefined }
```

The `process.env.space` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I stored my secrets within an .env, .env.build as well as added them to Now secrets through their CLI. To expose the secrets to the production build, I created a next.config.js file where I created a modules export like the following:

```
    module.exports = {
      env: {
        SPACE: process.env.SPACE,
      }
    };
```

My problem was that I accidentally added the next.config.js file to the gitignore which caused the env secrets to be returned as undefined.